# Como desactivar F5, Crtl-F5, Crtl-R y boton de reload de navegador cuando el focus este activo en inputs

Tags: php, javascript

quiero deshabilitar las teclas de "enter, F5, Crtl-F5, Crtl-R y boton de reload de navegador cuando el focus este activo en inputs

```
<script>
    document.onkeydown = function(e){
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    alert("No puedes actualizar pagina :)")
    if (tecla = 116) {return false;}
    }
</script>
```

y estos son los inputs donde quiero desactivar las funciones para actualizar

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" name="cantidad"   value="1" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Buscar productos" onkeyup="load(1)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando el evento `onbeforeunload()`:

```js
var preventF5 = (event) => {
  // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
  event.returnValue = '';
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_disable").on("click", () => {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', preventF5);
    });
  
    $("#btn_enable").on("click", () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", preventF5, false);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_disable">Disable Refresh</button>
<br/>
<button id="btn_enable">Enable Refresh</button>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVdXGa

Utilizando `onkeydown`

```js
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || (e.which || e.keyCode) == 82) e.preventDefault(); };

$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRwyZX

En lo personal, prefiero el uso de onbeforeunload.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Te sugiero, no obstante, que amplies las respuestas. Poner el código y decir que evento usan está bien, pero si además explicas que hace el evento, el usuario que pregunta y los posteriores que consultan, conseguiran un mayor entendimiento del script. Un saludo!.